# Evaluate a static variable in a class using debugger - using ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I do not have proper (source code is forcefully decompiled) source code of a swf file. Its a flash application. In a debug session, I want to evaluate a static variable in a specific class. Using MonsterDebugger, I can evaluate a variable in a OBJECT but I do not know how to evaluate a static variable in a CLASS (not Object of class). That is I know how to evaluate obj.var_name but not how to evaluate className.static_variable_name. Do you know?

Comment: Try querying any instance of that class for the var.

Answer (score 0):

First take class from instance

```
var myClass:Class = Object(myObj).constructor;
```

then ask for static variable name

```
myClass["VERSION"];//assuming that there is VERSION static variable
```

Comment: The problem I described is not directly answered by programming language (actionscript, in this case). It is related to facilities provided by actionscript debuggers like MonsterDebugger. I will repeat the question: in MonsterDebugger, how can I log (that is show) value of a static variable in a class. I have no problem showing value of non-static (and public) variables of objects, already